# aws-sdk-js ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down

Tags: javascript, jestjs, aws-sdk-js

I need to test whether a pre-signed url to bucket Amazon S3 was returned.

The Jest show the message below when run `yarn test`:

```sh
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at Object.userAgent (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:34:43)
      at HttpRequest.setUserAgent (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http.js:111:78)
      at new HttpRequest (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http.js:104:10)
      at MetadataService.request (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:93:23)
      at MetadataService.fetchMetadataToken (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:116:10)
```

That's the test:

**index.spec.js**

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const bucketName = 'bucket';
const key = 'image.png';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('should be able return pre signed url', () => {
    const s3SigV4Client = new AWS.S3({
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });
    
    const s3PreSignedUrl = s3SigV4Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key,
      Expires: 60,
    });

    expect(s3PreSignedUrl);
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "test_aws_sdk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.807.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Node.js and Yarn version installed:

```sh
$ node -v
v10.19.0
$ yarn -v
1.22.4
```

There's something I did wrong.

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the imports, add `jest.useFakeTimers()` in your test file:

Example:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

jest.useFakeTimers()

const bucketName = 'bucket';
const key = 'image.png';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('should be able return pre signed url', async () => {
    const s3SigV4Client = new AWS.S3({
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });
    
    const s3PreSignedUrl = s3SigV4Client.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key,
      Expires: 60,
    });

    expect(s3PreSignedUrl);
  });
});
```

Comment: I do not believe. Only that? 

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking instance:

```
  jest.mock('dynamoose', () => ({
    aws: new class {
      sdk = { config: { update: jest.fn((arg) => arg) } };
    },
    Schema: class { },
    Condition: class { },
    transaction: new class { },
    model: jest.fn(),
    logger: new class { },
    UNDEFINED: new class { },
    THIS: new class { },
    NULL: new class { },
  }));
```